# Is it possible to sync android ormlite across device?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, ormlite, data-synchronization

I am considering using ORMLite for persistance in an android app. A requirement is to be able to sync the underlying android SQlite database across multiple android devices.

Is this possible with ORMLite? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly copy the database file over to another device and it will work if you didn't change the schema.

I wouldn't recomment that though. Instead you could load the Object tree from your db using ORMLite, copy it over, and write it back to the db with ORMLite. You might want to look into SyncAdapters too.

Comment: Copying the whole dB is not an Option. ORMlite with SyncAdapters - any experience with that?

Comment: But copying the whole object graph is essentially the same as copying the whole sqlite file, IMHO.

Comment: Never tried ORMLite with SyncAdapters myself, that was just an idea. Essentially it would be the same as copying the sqlite file but you wouldn't have to worry about schema changes, e.g. if you to add/remove columns.

Comment: Haven't thought about schema changes yet, but that is an issue, right. Although Android is IMHO superior to iOS, in this regard iOS shines with CoreData and iCloud, making synchronisation easy. This is seriously missing in Android.